# Does dying and getting revived restore your kill streak?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

Say I currently have a 5 kill streak. If I die, get revived by a medic, then proceed to get another kill, will I get a Combat Efficiency pin?

Comment: All right, the user has already selected an answer, but I need proof, you understand? PROOF! :)

So, all you need is provide a demo showing that dying indeed resets a killstreak in order to get the bounty.

Comment: Since i don't usually get a killstreak, and i don't usually record while playing, i will not be able to provide a demo right now. I'll just try to find an empty server and make a proof with some friends' help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

When you die, everything is reset, except equipment and ammo you were wearing, which are reset on regular respawn.
Thus, your kill streak is reset.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if killstreak is kept because even if revived you still get a death recorded into your profile, so from game's point of view reviving doesn't cancel death. Even C4 you planted disappears (it disappears exactly at the moment of reviving, not dying - just like after regular respawning). So reviving must be just a faster respawn option after death without ammo reset.

Comment: I would agree, even if I didn't check this in-game. It clearly makes sense. You don't deserve a pin if you die in the middle of the pin's requirements :)

Comment: has anyone tested this yet?